# Регулярное выражение для разбиения строки по первому вхождению разделителя

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Помогите с составлением регулярного выражения.
Имеется строка `a=b=c=d=e`. Её требуется разбить(split) по по первому знаку `=`.

Т.е. на выходе должен получится следующий массив

```
["a", "b=c=d=e"]
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var string = "a=b=c=d=e";

/**
 * раз
 */
var match = string.match(/(\w)=(.*)/);
console.log(match);

/**
 * два
 */
var split = string.split('='),
    array = [];

array.push(split[0]);
array.push(split.slice(1, split.length).join('='));

console.log(array);
```

Добавлено:

```
string.split(/^([^=]+)=/).slice(1);
```

Comment: В таком случае я могу предложить следующее:

str = "a=b=c=d=e";
reg = /^([^=]+)=/;

str.split(reg);
//["", "a", "b=c=d=e"]

Просто думал сделать красиво и просто получив массив:
["a", "b=c=d=e"]

Comment: м? string.split(/^([^=]+)=/).slice(1)

Comment: Туплю. Добавьте в ответ, пометил как верный.

Comment: Все равно интересно можно ли только одной регуляркой разбить строку.